# Streaming video FTP with JSF 2.2

Tags: jsf

Well, i have a WebApp (JSF 2.2) and FTP in the same server. This WebApp can access FTP video files, users can download and upload, this works very well. But now user need to view video through browser.

How can i streaming ftp video in browser ? I want to avoid download video to WebApp folder because are big videos (like 4GB and more), there is anyway ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the HTML5 player like:

```
<video  controls>
    <source src="#{pathToYourVideo}" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

Change the type to your video type.
See also http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp